# Add custom header using Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, header

I've been trying to add custom header to the webpage using Selenium c# but I can't figure out if it's possible.

It can't be performed directly using Selenium so I tried to use proxy mob and fiddler libraries, some other stuff, but nothing worked.
Do you guys have some working solution for this case? I'm using Chrome browser if it's important

Comment: It looks like you are describing a proposed solution to the problem. I don't think we can answer your question based on the information you provided. Can you [edit] your question to focus on the problem you need solved which is causing you to want to add an HTTP header using Selenium? That might be solvable.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm trying to add my custom header when I launch Selenium test, to the browser.
So for API test, for example I can use next code
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Skip-Validation, "True");
but I can't find any working solution for UI test

Comment: Ok. So *that's* the true problem.